# Trying to click enter on android keyboard

Tags: javascript, android, appium, ui-automation, appium-android

My tests run under browserstack with appium 1.20.2 and wdio 7.7.3 using javascript.
I need to click on enter in the mobile (android) keyboard after entering a text in a field to go to another page.

I tried this:

```
driver.pressKeyCode(66);
```

But nothing happened. I only see the cursor moving inside the field that’s all.
Just to precise the keyboard isn’t shown while the tests are running I don’t know if it’s the reason why nothing happened.
I also tried this `driver.execute('mobile: performEditorAction', {'action': 'done'});`

I tried to click on the field before entering the email, I entered it and did the pressKeyCode(66) but nothing has worked.
[the app interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DlHRZ.png)

Can anyone help me please?

Thank you

image

Comment: Not sure about your environment, but there is a long standing bug in Android that causes keyCode to be unknown in browser JavaScript. https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=809107

Answer (score 1):

I have finally found a solution. It worked by using this command:

```
driver.execute('mobile: performEditorAction', {'action': 'Done'});
```

I wrote 'done' instead of 'Done' that's why it didn't work

This one hasn't worked for me `driver.pressKeyCode(66);`